# Mysterious Jboss shutdown

Tags: java, jboss

We have a several application deployed in Jboss server. From last few month its observed that jboss servers gets killed without logging any error or exception neither in any application log nor in Jboss server log. The crash is not periodic and happens randomly. The crash is very silent (similar to kill -9 )and its become extremely difficult to debug the root cause.From our analysis one thing sure its not out of memory issue.We analysed the syslog as well, nothing suspicious found. Is possible to force VM to generate error log before the process crash due to any reason.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is "Is possible to force VM to generate error log before the process crash due to any reason?" but the question isn't asked until the end. Nor does the title indicate what your question is. You should edit the title and the question to be more clear.

Comment: We used to have very similar problem in our system - the server would simply "die" if it was idle for a longer period of time (by "idle" I mean no user activity). Our workaround was to create a simple scheduled bean that would print the current time to `System.out` every 10 minutes or so. Not very nice, but we haven't had enough time to trace the root cause... and the server is alive since then, so it is at least somewhat improved.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM logs fatal errors to `hs_err_<pid>.log` files

You can [change the location of the fatal log file](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html#gbwcy) using `java -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/java/java_error%p.log`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problem using JBoss EAP 6 in Linux enviroment, when system memory is almost gone the S.O kill some process, normally the file hs_err_pidxxx.log  with crash report are generated inside bin directory of JBoss. Other case that process is killed is when you are using JBoss with DC mode, when instance stay long time without communication with DC, the process is finalized, I dont know why.